# im making a bot that uses 8ball, so it says that 'random' is not a var but how else can i do, random answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
@client.command(aliases=['8ball', 'test'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses =['As I see it, yes.',
                'Ask again later.',
                'Better not tell you now.',
                'Cannot predict now.',
                'Concentrate and ask again.',
                'Don’t count on it.',
                'It is certain.',
                'It is decidedly so.',
                'Most likely.',
                'My reply is no.',
                'My sources say no.',
                'Outlook not so good.',
                'Outlook good.',
                'Reply hazy, try again.',
                'Signs point to yes.',
                'Very doubtful.',
                'Without a doubt.',
                'Yes.',
                'Yes – definitely.',
                'You may rely on it.']
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')
```

Comment: Do you have an `import random` line at the top of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import random
@client.command(aliases=['8ball', 'test'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses =['As I see it, yes.',
                'Ask again later.',
                'Better not tell you now.',
                'Cannot predict now.',
                'Concentrate and ask again.',
                'Don’t count on it.',
                'It is certain.',
                'It is decidedly so.',
                'Most likely.',
                'My reply is no.',
                'My sources say no.',
                'Outlook not so good.',
                'Outlook good.',
                'Reply hazy, try again.',
                'Signs point to yes.',
                'Very doubtful.',
                'Without a doubt.',
                'Yes.',
                'Yes – definitely.',
                'You may rely on it.']
    responce = random.choice(responses)
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {responce}')
```